# Booting from a persistent live usb on MX linux and enabling systemd?

Tags: linux, boot, encryption, kernel, parameters

I have created a Live USB with persistent storage using MX Linux since they offer a few tools which makes it easier.
After booting and installing a bunch of applications I was not able to enable the application since it said that systemd is not loaded.
I searched online and found out that I need to add this kernel parameters  `quiet splash init=/lib/systemd/systemd` but when I clicked on apply it gave an error: Can not chroot in to the environment. I am guessing this is due to the fact that I have encryption enabled.

Is there a way I can add these kernel parameters without messing up the live usb?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you're trying to make an encrypted USB drive with persistent storage.

Most likely it's not your kernel parameters that are the problem, but the initramfs (often called initrd).

The initramfs is responsible for loading filesystems and kernel modules that the kernel cannot load by itself. An example of this is an encrypted disk - the kernel cannot load this on its own. The initramfs has to be made to allow this - it isn't automatic.

If you are trying to make an encrypted USB drive with persistence, I'd honestly suggest just installing the OS directly onto your USB.

Comment: Hi, I just checked with MX Linux devs and they mentioned that systemd is not available on live USB instead it has sysVinit

Comment: ah, makes sense now. I'm surprised by that, but you should still be able to install the whole OS onto the USB and use systemd as the init system. I've done it before on other distros and it works flawlessly in my experience.

Comment: Yes, I am aware but I don't know how to setup persistent option and the easiest one I know is offered by MX Linux so I opted for it